# Cambiar la primera letra de un texto

Tags: r, regex

Tengo estos datos

```
datos <- read.table(text = 'col1
"Casa Verde 2015_HU/AJE/9999/2017"
"Casa Roja 2015_HU/AJE/0263/2000"
"Casa Verde_U/AJE/4441/2017"
"Casa Verde_HU/AJE/22225/2017_F4"
"Casa Azul 5_HU/AJE/1111/2017_B2"
"Casa Verde_HU/AJE/0000/2017_76"
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

La tercera fila `Casa Verde_U/AJE/4441/2017` empieza por U/AJE y quiero cambiarlo a HU/AJE

Pero si hago

```
datos$col2 <- gsub("U/AJE", "HU/AJE", datos$col1)
```

Los HU del resto de filas se convierten en HHU. Quiero que cambie solo el que empieza por U.

He probado con ^U/AJE, pero tampoco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Busca directamente el patrón `_U` o ' U' y reempla la `U` por `HU`:

```
datos$col2 <- gsub("([_| ])U(/AJE)", "\\1HU\\2", datos$col1)
```

Este es un patrón de match y captura, "matchea" el espacio o guion, mas el texto `U/AJE` y con `\\1HU\\2`, solo reemplazamos la `U` por `HU`. Los patrones `\\1` y `\\2` agregan los textos capturados `([_| ])` y `(/AJE)`

Comment: Y si no siempre empezara por _U? A veces empieza por espacio en blanco, pero no lo puse en el ejemplo. Como por ejemplo  Casa Azul 5 U/AJE/1111/2017_B2

Comment: Si es un conjunto finito de caracteres antes de la `U` puedes usar el `or`, por ejemplo `[_| ]`. Revisa mi edición.